# Cannot read Android Partition Image created using ADB

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, adb, partitions, motorola-droid-x2

I am currently working on a Mobile Forensics demonstration for my college's computer science capstone. For this demonstration I have been trying to create a partition image of the an old Droid x2 user partition and then examine the resulting data using forensic software. However neither FTK imager, nor Autopsy have been able to read the created image files.
I have been working with a rooted Droid x2 running 2.3.5, and have been using Android ADB to try and create a dd image.

```
  'adb shell dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p16 > userdata.dd'
```

This command seems to work and creates an appropriate sized image file but various forensic software give errors such as 'does not contain valid evidence.'

I have tried creating .bin, and .img files to similar effects.